# How to view the slices of a 3d image separately in Open3d Python?

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, open3d, stl-format

I am new to Open3d. I have a 3D image and I want to view the slices of that 3D image separately.I have this code where I can view the image in a window.

```
import open3d as o3d
mesh=o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("MyImage.stl")
mesh=mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh],window_name="STL",left=1000,top=2000,width=800,height=650)
```

Note: The image is a stl type file.

Is there a way where I can view all the slices in the same window but separately? Also can some one suggest if open3d library is good enough for research in medical images as it creates a mesh

Comment: "it creates a mesh" - no, it just reads the mesh from .stl file, the mesh is saved in the .stl file, it's not a "3D" image per se. It's up to you to code it to view the slices

Comment: You should not reduce a 3D image to a mesh. The grayscale (or color) information in the image is much richer than a set of boundaries between regions. In some instances it’s fine to extract boundaries and render then in 3D, but not always. So it depends on what your application is.

Comment: I don't see OP having a "3d image" at all. it's just an STL, a mesh. question needs clarity.